# Store line by line elements in array C language

Tags: arrays, c, file

i'm trying to read a .txt file having in every line a name and a age and store them in an array, but apparently only the last line name is being stored on all of positions of array

My .txt file content:

```
Pedro 14
Erica 17
Paulo 23
Carlos 27
Mendes 30
Augusto 31
Geraldo 32
```

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
   FILE *f = fopen("nomes.txt" , "r");
   char name[20];
   char* listnames[10];
   int cont;

   while(fscanf(f, "%s %d", name) != EOF) {
        listnames[cont] = name;
        cont++;
   }

   fclose(f);

   for (int i=0; i<cont; i++) {
       printf("%s ", listnames[i]);
   }
}
```

Output:

```
Geraldo Geraldo Geraldo Geraldo Geraldo Geraldo Geraldo
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of issues in your code:

**First:**

```
FILE *f = fopen("nomes.txt" , "r");
```

What if opening the file fails?

**Second:**

`cont` is not initialized. You may want to initialize it to 0.

**Third:**

```
fscanf(f, "%s %d", name)
```

You are scanning for a `char*` and an `int`, but you are only passing one argument (i.e. `name`).

**Fourth:**

```
char* listnames[10];
...
listnames[cont] = name;
```

Here, `listnames[cont]` is not initialized. And you are assigning the adress of `name` to every `listnames` entry. You may want to use `strdup()` to allocate space for your strings, or use a static array for that matter.

---

Here is how your code should look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *f = fopen("nomes.txt" , "r");
    if (!f) { // Handle failure
        perror("Could not open file");
        return 1;
    }
    
    char name[20];
    int number;
    char* listnames[10]; // (*) char listnames[10][20];
    int numbers[10];
    int count = 0;
    
    while(fscanf(f, "%s %d", name, &number) != EOF && count < 10) {
        listnames[count] = strdup(name); // (*) strcpy(listnames[count], name);
        numbers[count] = number; // If you want to save the numbers
        count++;
    }
    
    fclose(f);
    
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        printf("%s %d\n", listnames[i], numbers[i]);
        free(listnames[i]); // Free space allocated by strdup()
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have forgotten to initialize the cont to zero before entering the while loop.

Answer (score -1):

While @user2134584's comment is correct, the main problem is that you are only allocating a single buffer, then having each of the pointers reference that same, single buffer.

Allocating an array of `char` pointers does *not* allocate space for the strings they point to.

Instead, what you need to do is something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
   FILE *f = fopen("nomes.txt" , "r");
   char listnames[10][20];
   int discard = 0;
   int cont = 0;

   while(fscanf(f, "%20s %d", listnames[cont], &discard) != EOF) {
       cont++;
   }

   fclose(f);

   for (int i=0; i<cont; i++) {
       printf("%s ", listnames[i]);
   }
}
```

Note that I haven't tested this code, but it should at least put you on the right track.